# InAppPurchase with Subcription type

Tags: objective-c, ios4, in-app-purchase

How to add InAppPurchase with Subscription type in my iPhone application?

Answer (score 0):

You can just read that in In-App Purchase Programming Guide
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW2